# Why does HttpClient require httpasyncclient?

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpcomponents

I have written a straightforward Java HTTP client application using Spring and Apache HTTPComponents. When I run it, it fails with the exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/nio/client/HttpAsyncClient
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at my.package.<init>(MyClientTest.java:60)
```

The code on this line is:

```
 private final RestTemplate restTemplate = 
     new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

I can cure this by adding a dependency to my build:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

But why do I need to do this? I'm not doing anything explicitly asynchronous. I thought Maven was supposed to automatically bring in necessary dependencies.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek As a corporate coder, I have little choice in the matter. But it doesn't cause us any major problems.

Comment: To the close voter -- I added this Q&A because I spent half a day finding the issue, and wished SO had the answer. Quite a lot of people have asked similar questions elsewhere about this specific class, and just got the answer that they should get the async jar in their classpath. I suspect that in most cases they didn't really need it.

Comment: Could you post the entire stacktrace, what class are you loading when this issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you haven't accidentally asked for an async request factory - for example:

```
private final RestTemplate restTemplate = 
     new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

When I encountered this, IDE autocomplete gave me `HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory` -- presumably because it comes before `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` alphabetically, and I didn't look carefully enough to see `Async` tucked away in there.

`HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory` is part of Spring, and has a runtime dependency on Apache's `HttpAsyncClient`.

If you instead use `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`, you will not need the `httpasyncclient` jar.